# How to get length of allocatable string?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: Code::Blocks 20.03 ( compiler: mingw 9.2.0 )

The example code is:

```
program string_operation

implicit none

character(:), allocatable :: name_aa
character(*),   parameter :: name = '("abc123")'

allocate( character( len_trim( name ) ) :: name_aa )

write( name_aa, name )

print *, len_trim( name )
print *, len_stri( name_aa )
print *,           name
print *,           name_aa

contains

function len_stri( string_tmp ) result( data_tmp )

  implicit none

  character(*), intent( in ) :: string_tmp
  integer                    ::   data_tmp

  do data_tmp = len( string_tmp ), 1, -1

    if ( string_tmp( data_tmp : data_tmp ) .ne. " " ) return

  end do

end function len_stri

end program string_operation
```

The result in console is:
`10`
`6`
`'("abc123")'`
`abc123`

Why the length of `name` is `10` but after allocation the length of `name_aa` is `6`. 
They need to be same, or?

Comment: name is a format. Using it you only write "abc123" into name_aa - the rest is padded with blanks. So your function returns 6 which is the length of name_aa without trailing blanks. Try printing out Len( name_aa ). But why don't you just use Len_trim for name_aa which should do the same as your function?

Comment: Why do you think the length of `name_aa` after allocation is 6?  Its length is 10 but, as Ian Bush details, this is padded with four trailing blanks after the internal write.  If you use `len(name_aa)` you should expect to see 10 not 6.

Comment: I am new to this programming language so I want to learn things that are not clear to me. Here it is not clear to me why lenght is 10 if the length of abc123 is 6?